# Can't get python to replace row in csv (creates new row instead)

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, csv, row

```
def deletedata(uniquecode):
    with open('Stallingsbestand.csv', 'r+') as CSV:
        writer = csv.writer(CSV, delimiter=';')
        for row in CSV:
             if uniquecode in row:
                 writer.writerow((uniquecode, ''))
```

in `Stallingsbestand.csv` consists of rows that look like this:

```
uniquecode;Date_of_last_opening_a_function
```

I want to be able to delete the date of last opening and just have the unique code there.

(appending `False` at the end of the row can work too but I don't know which is easier)

I thought that just overwriting the row would be the easiest but I can't get it to work. Is there anyone who knows how to make this work?

Comment: what is `naam` here?? Paste some rows of your csv here

Comment: You want to read and write in the same file within the loop?

Comment: I apologize, naam is used in the code but isn't english I tried to translate and simplify it as much as possible. so now it is uniquecode

Answer (score 1):

You want to rename the file to `Stallingsbestand.old`, and write out a new version of `Stallingsbestand.csv`. One way to do this is to copy (sometimes) modified rows from a `csv.reader` to a `csv.writer` within a loop, similar to your current code.

You might find it more convenient to create an in-memory dataframe with `pandas.read_csv()`, mutate one of its rows, and then persist it with `pandas.to_csv()`.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html